# When making Javascript files locally available in function, first time it's not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

In my master page I am having one button, onclick this button intend to open a page in popup. For popup I have one javascript file. Now I want this file to load locally inside click function.

Now problem is first time it is not working and there after its working fine.

On click for first time of the button I am getting following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenModelWindow is not defined**

But after that it's working fine. Here is my code:

```
 $('#<%=btnAddEvent.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
    var script; var EventType="Task";   
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "../Calendar/JS/wdCalendar/src/Plugins/Common.js";  //OpenModelWindow is defined here
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

     var url = "../Calendar/add.aspx" + EventType;                

                OpenModelWindow(url,
                { width: 660, height: 400,
                    caption: newcaption,

                });
                return false;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong I am doing so that I am not getting desired result first time.

Comment: Is `url` expected to be `"../Calendar/add.aspxTask"`?

Comment: My guess is that after you append, the script is not yet fully loaded, that's why using functions from it right away will throw and second call is fine. You should wait until it's ready/loaded and then use OpenModelWindow function. Another problem is I see is that you are appending every time you click it's unnecessary isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery done method and now it works for me...

```
 $.getScript('../Calendar/JS/wdCalendar/src/Plugins/Common.js').done(function(){
            OpenModelWindow(url,
                { width: 660, height: 400,
                    caption: newcaption,

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

**First**

Load script on document ready and the use your button click to open model
like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var script;    
script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "../Calendar/JS/wdCalendar/src/Plugins/Common.js";  //OpenModelWindow is defined here
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

});
```

Now open modal in button click

```
$('#<%=btnAddEvent.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
 var EventType="Task";   
 var url = "../Calendar/add.aspx" + EventType;                
 OpenModelWindow(url,
            { width: 660, height: 400,
                caption: newcaption,

            });
            return false;
}
```

**Second**

if you want to load script only when button clicked load script from jquery and perform open modal after script loaded like this

```
$('#<%=btnAddEvent.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {

$.getScript( "../Calendar/JS/wdCalendar/src/Plugins/Common.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
 if(jqxhr.status == 200)
   {
      var EventType="Task";   
      var url = "../Calendar/add.aspx" + EventType;                
      OpenModelWindow(url,
            { width: 660, height: 400,
                caption: newcaption,

            });
            return false;

      }
});
```

Comment: But I have to load more than one script. Now I have tried to load like this 
'  $.getScript("../Calendar/JS/wdCalendar/src/Plugins/Common.js");' 
but still it's not working first time and then it's working.